# iOS Designable Button Background color don't work

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, ibdesignable

I created a custom UIButton with this code:

```
@implementation HGButton

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
 {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self initVariables];
        [self customInit];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self initVariables];
        [self customInit];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self customInit];
}

- (void)setNeedsLayout
{
    [super setNeedsLayout];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)prepareForInterfaceBuilder
{
    [self customInit];
}

-(void) initVariables
{
    self.fillColor          = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    self.borderWidth        = 2;
    self.cornerRadious      = 10;
}

- (void)customInit
{
    [self setBackgroundColor:self.fillColor];

    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadious;
    self.layer.borderWidth = self.borderWidth;

    if (self.cornerRadious > 0) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }
}
```

it's a very simple code. When add my button to a view in storyboard it looks perfect. 
But when I play the app the button background color is always light grey. 
When I press the button it's background color change to the color selected in storyboard.

Why this? Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are not updating the background color when `self.fillcolor` has been changed through storyboard.

Assuming you have this

```
@property (nonatomic, copy)   IBInspectable UIColor *fillcolor;
```

Add the following code in your class

```
- (void)setFillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor {
    if (fillColor != _fillColor) {
        _fillColor = fillColor;
        [self customInit];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a 'set method' to monitor fillColor.

```
    - (void)setFillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor
 {
    _fillColor = fillColor;
    self.backgroundColor = fillColor;

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your class

```
- (void)setFillColor:(UIColor *)fillColor {
    self.backgroundColor = fillColor;
}
```